# Avoid ng-content wrapper Angular2

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, transclusion

I'm trying to style the sibling of an element that is 'injected' by an ng-content block. When I apply this selector in the css `*[class*="item"]:hover + .skewer` it works perfectly with the elements that already exists in the component template. The problem comes when I expect that selector to work with the elements passed to the ng-content too. Since it creates a 'wrapping' div around the element I pass in, the `.skewer` element it's no more a direct sibling of the hovered element, so it won't apply the rules.

To clarify what I'm trying to do here's a snippet of the component template:

```
<nav id="navbar" class="navbar navbar-met fixed-top bg-faded">
    <div class="left-block">
        <!-- Framework logo -->
        <div class="navbar-square-item pointer met-blue-hover">
            <span class="met-logo-wrp">{{brandFirstLetter}}</span>
        </div>

        <!-- Concerned application initials -->
        <a class="navbar-square-item pointer met-blue-hover" *ngIf="appInitials">
            <span class="app-initials-wrp">{{appInitials}}</span>
        </a>

        <!-- The components passed to the navbar with attribute left-block-item will be rendered here -->
        <!-- Remember to use the proper element class (square or rect) -->
        <ng-content select="[left-block-item]"></ng-content>

        <!-- This is the block that contains the gradient with the inclined bars -->
        <div class="skewer"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="middle-block">
        <!-- The components passed to the navbar with attribute middle-block-item will be rendered here -->
        <!-- Remember to use the proper element class (square or rect) -->
        <ng-content select="[middle-block-item]"></ng-content>
    </div>

    <div class="right-block">
        <!-- The components passed to the navbar with attribute right-block-item will be rendered here -->
        <!-- Remember to use the proper element class (square or rect) -->
        <ng-content select="[right-block-item]"></ng-content>

        <!-- This is the block that contains the gradient with the inclined bars flipped -->
        <div class="skewer flip-horizontal last-flex-element"></div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

And here's the complete css rule:

```
*[class*="item"]:hover + .skewer{
    background: 
    linear-gradient(
        60deg, 
        $nav-bar-item-sel-bg, 
        $nav-bar-item-sel-bg 38%, 
        $palette-white 40%, 
        $palette-white 47%, 
        $nav-bar-item-bg 49%,
        $nav-bar-item-bg 58%,
        $palette-white 60%,
        $palette-white);
}
```

Finally the 'external' component that uses the nav component:

```
<sfw-navbar [appInitials]="'Pt'">

    <div left-block-item>
        <div class="navbar-square-item met-blue-hover">
            <span class="mdi mdi-magnify navbar-icon"></span>
        </div>
    </div>

</sfw-navbar>
```

When passing that HTML element in that way, the problem comes out.

Even a suggestion on what to search it'll be really helpful, I've already Googled a lot, but I can't think at anything more to search than 'ng-content transculsion options' and all the combinations that comes with...

Also if the question is not 100% clear I encourage you to let me know that, I'm completely blind this time with this 'need'

Any help is appreciated!